# Sound sensor's embedded green light blinking with noise but external LED not

Tags: audio, sensors, arduino-uno, led

I bought a sound sensor ( 3 pins VCC GND OUT).
I connected all the pins correctly (I think)

```
VCC to 5V
GND to GND
OUT to A0
```

But when I upload the code into the arduino uno then the internal green light of sound sensor is blinking with the sound like music. But any LED at breadboard doesn't.
the value of the function `sensorValue = analogRead(A0);` return almost same value while making noise. After calibrating the sensor the value is also almost same.
Here my Code

```
#define out A0
int th = 320;
int sensorValue = 0;


int pins[3] = {10,11,12};

void setup(){

  int i;
  for( i = 0; i<3; i++ ){
     pinMode(pins[i], OUTPUT);
  }

  //pinMode(out,INPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop(){
//  sensorValue = analogRead(OUT);
  sensorValue = analogRead(out);
  int chk = digitalRead(out);
  Serial.print("sensorValue: ");
  Serial.println(sensorValue);

  Serial.print("digitalRead: ");
  Serial.println(chk);

  int i=0;
  if( sensorValue > th){
    for( i = 0; i<3; i++){
       digitalWrite(pins[i],HIGH); 
    }
  }else{
   for( i = 0; i<3; i++){
       digitalWrite(pins[i],LOW); 
    }   
  }


}
```

What's wrong with it?